# Solving the IVP $8y''+26y=0$, $y(0)=2$, and $y'(0)=7$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Im supposed to find $y$ as a function of $t$ given the equation:

$$8y''+26y=0$$

Initial values are $y(0)=2$ and $y'(0)=7$.

I found the function of $y$ is $y=c_1\cos (\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}t)+c_2\sin(\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}t)$. Then I take the derivative, $y'=-\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}c_1 \sin (\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}t)+\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}c_2\cos (\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}t)$. Then using the initial values i'd solve for both arbitrary constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ and I ended up getting $2$ and $\frac{14}{\sqrt{13}}$. However this answer isn't correct. There's gotta be a mistake somewhere but I've been struggling to find it.

Comment: Please format your question, and show the work you did to obtain those values.

Comment: im not sure how to format it

Comment: [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Is this how you wanted it? Furthermore, you need to learn how to write in latex if your going to ask questions. It's a good skill anyways.

Comment: How do you know the answer isn't correct?  Do you know what the correct answer is?

Answer (score 1):

The DE's characteristic equation has two distinct complex roots: $+\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}i$ and $-\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}i$, so the general solution (indefinite integral) is:

$$y=c_1\cos (\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}t)+c_2\sin(\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}t)$$

**First** initial condition, $y(0)=2$:

$$2=c_1\cos (\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}0)+c_2\sin(\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}0) \implies c_1=2$$

**Second** initial condition, $y'(0)=7$:

$$y'=-\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}c_1 \sin (\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}t)+\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}c_2\cos (\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}t)$$

$$7=-\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}c_1 \sin (\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}0)+\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}c_2\cos (\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}0) \implies c_2=\frac{14}{\sqrt{13}}$$

Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use Laplace transform:

$$8y''(t)+26y(t)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[8y''(t)+26y(t)
\right]_{(s)}=\mathcal{L}_t\left[0\right]_{(s)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[8y''(t)\right]_{(s)}+\mathcal{L}_t\left[26y(t)
\right]_{(s)}=\mathcal{L}_t\left[0\right]_{(s)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$8\cdot\mathcal{L}_t\left[y''(t)\right]_{(s)}+26\cdot\mathcal{L}_t\left[y(t)
\right]_{(s)}=\mathcal{L}_t\left[0\right]_{(s)}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Now, use:

- $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[y(t)
  \right]_{(s)}=\text{Y}(s)$$
- $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[y''(t)
  \right]_{(s)}=s^2\text{Y}(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)$$
- $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[0
  \right]_{(s)}=0$$

  ---

$$8\cdot\left(s^2\text{Y}(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)\right)+26\text{Y}(s)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Use the intitial conditions $y(0)=2$ and $y'(0)=7$:

---

$$8\cdot\left(s^2\text{Y}(s)-2s-7\right)+26\text{Y}(s)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$8s^2\text{Y}(s)-16s-56+26\text{Y}(s)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\text{Y}(s)\left[8s^2+26\right]=16s+56\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\text{Y}(s)=\frac{16s+56}{8s^2+26}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\text{Y}(s)\right]_{(t)}=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{16s+56}{8s^2+26}\right]_{(t)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(t)=2\cos\left(\frac{t\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)+\frac{14\sin\left(\frac{t\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{13}}$$

Answer (score 0):

What you say you did isnt correct.  But you don't show exactly what you did or how you know it was not correct!  Yes, the general solution to this equation is $y(t)= c_1\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}t\right)+ c_2 sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}t\right)$.  Yes, $y'(t)= -c_1\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}t\right)+ c_2\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2} cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}t\right)$.

Setting t= 0, $y(0)= c_1= 2$ and $y'(0)= c_2\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}= 7$ so $c_2= \frac{14}{\sqrt{13}}= \frac{14\sqrt{13}}{13}$.  You say that is not correct.  How do you know that?

Answer (score -1):

With free Computer Algebra System Maxima 5.42.1:[image]